# How to get all parent div height and width separately if their childs are different using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have parent divs named - "*main*" and "*sq*" , they have same name child called "*s*" which both are designed (width and height) using javascript, so I want to make the both div named "*s*" different width and height according to their parent with

both child div ( class - "*s*") height and width should be in ratio to 1.5 to their parent div

the ***main***'s child is success to get the div in ratio but ***sq***'s not.

and I've found the problem in ( *e.parentNode.clientWidth & e.parentNode.clientHeight* ) which is only taking the ***main***'s width and height not the ***sq***'s.

Simply , the the black div inside orange is in ratio to 1.5 but green's not ?

check here -http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAO5SWY5KETB

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="main" style="width:400px;height:500px;background-color:orange">
<div class="s" style="background-color:black">xfgx</div>
</div>
<div class="sq" style="width:250px;height:500px;background-color:green;">
<div class="s" style="background-color:black;">xfgx</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    }
.row {
    clear:both;
    width:100pc;
}
.main,.sq{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
var sms = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("s"), 0);
 sms.forEach(function(e) {
    var w = window.innerWidth - e.parentNode.clientWidth ;
    var h = window.innerHeight - e.parentNode.clientHeight ;
    var MW = w - ( w / 1.5 );
    var MH = h - ( h / 1.5 );
    e.style.width = MW + 'px';
    e.style.height = MH + 'px';
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML= e.parentNode.clientWidth ;
});
```

Comment: what's this .row {
    clear:both;
    width:100**pc**;

Comment: sq 's child width is not according to their parent

Comment: when you say ratio, you mean `parent-width/child-width = 1.5` ?

Comment: Solution to your answer - do not use `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight` in `var w = window.innerWidth - e.parentNode.clientWidth;` & `var h = window.innerHeight - e.parentNode.clientHeight ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the parent width that you can get either with [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) or with [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) depending on how want width and height calculation relatively to padding/scrollbars:

With `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
var sms = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("s"), 0);
sms.forEach(function(e) {
  var parentRect = e.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
  var MW = parentRect.width - (parentRect.width / 1.5);
  var MH = parentRect.height - (parentRect.height / 1.5);
  e.style.width = MW + 'px';
  e.style.height = MH + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100pc;
}
.main,
.sq {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main" style="width:400px;height:500px;background-color:orange">
    <div class="s" style="background-color:black">xfgx</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sq" style="width:250px;height:500px;background-color:green;">
    <div class="s" style="background-color:black;">xfgx</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With `clientWidth`:

```js
var sms = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("s"), 0);
sms.forEach(function(e) {
  var w = e.parentNode.clientWidth;
  var h = e.parentNode.clientHeight;
  var MW = w - (w / 1.5);
  var MH = h - (h / 1.5);
  e.style.width = MW + 'px';
  e.style.height = MH + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100pc;
}
.main,
.sq {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main" style="width:400px;height:500px;background-color:orange">
    <div class="s" style="background-color:black">xfgx</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sq" style="width:250px;height:500px;background-color:green;">
    <div class="s" style="background-color:black;">xfgx</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to calculate the children's width with respect to the parent's width then there is no need to include the `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight`.

The `window.innerWidth` has a constant value of say 945px, which you are subtracting from the parent's width using this line below

```
var w = window.innerWidth - e.parentNode.clientWidth;
```

but why?? **This will mess up your calculations.**

Just use

```
var w = e.parentNode.clientWidth;
var h = e.parentNode.clientHeight;
```

This should fix your problem & calculate ONLY as per your parent width & height.